# Import all images from json file with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I need to import all images from a JSON file to work with an app using Webpack. I don't imagine it matters but the images are used as background images. Im currently doing this:

```
import image1 from './img/1.jpg';
import image2 from './img/2.jpg';

const content = [
  {
    img: image1
  },
  {
    img: image2
  }
]

function applyContent() {
  someElement.style.backgroundImage = `url(${content[1].img})`;
}
```

This is working but in reality there will be far more values in `content` and I would like to be able to load an external JSON file. I would also like the solution to work with different numbers of images.

How can this be done? I was thinking about using a for loop to iterate over the array length but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner solution?

Comment: Why not just base64 encode (dataURL) all the images and save them in a json file?

Comment: Ive simplified my code. In reality there are a lot of images so it would be better to lazy load them.